# Vector of linearly spaced vectors with different steps

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Say we have a vector:

```
dx = [ 1 10 20 ]
```

Now we want to generate a linearly spaced vector from 0-100 in steps of dx for each value in dx so that we get something like the following, call it vals:

```
vals = 0   0  0
       1  10 20
       2  20 40
       3  30 60
       .  .   .
       .  . 100
       . 100
      100
```

So that we arrive at an vector of differently sized vectors. Eventually we'll want to apply a function to vals and then we need to sum up the inner vectors so that the result will be a vector with 3 elements.
What's the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with `arrayfun` and `cellfun`:

```
dx = [1 10 20];
vals = arrayfun(@(x)0:x:100, dx, 'UniformOutput', false);

result = cellfun(@(x)sum(someFunction(x)), vals);
```

where `someFunction` is the function you want to apply to the vectors.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I haven't any experience with arrayfun and cellfun so I'll have to play with them some more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I put the result in a list since the columns are not the same size and it won't fit in an array.

```
dx = [1 10 20];
l = 1 + 100 ./ dx;
% disp(l); % so you can see what the above calculation did
vals = {linspace(0,100,l(1,1))', linspace(0,100,l(1,2))',linspace(0,100,l(1,3))}
% the (') after the linspace() function is a matrix transpose since linspace() returns a row vector
% lists work like matrices except you use list_name{m} as opposed to matrix_name(m,n)
```

Have fun with vectorization!

Comment: I suggest you don't call your array `length`, since this is the name of a frequently-used builtin function.

Comment: This only works for a fixed length of dx. I was looking for something scalable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for your correction, my Octave/Matlab is a bit rusty. :)